# sed to remove all pipe symbols from file and insert tab

Tags: sed

I am trying to remove the `|` at the end of `$3` and insert a `tab` using `sed`, but currently only the `|` is getting removed and this will not work in my `awk` command later.  Is there a better way?  Thank you :).

**input**

```
chr1    955542  955763|AGRN
chr1    957570  957852|AGRN
chr1    976034  976270|AGRN
chr1    976542  976787|AGRN
```

**sed**

```
sed 's/<|>/TAB/g' input > out
```

**current output**

```
chr1    955542  955763AGRN
chr1    957570  957852AGRN
chr1    976034  976270AGRN
chr1    976542  976787AGRN
```

Comment: That sed command does not output what you write. There's something you're not telling us.

Comment: "Is there a better way?" Well if you are using awk anyway, why not configure its field separator (option `-F` or `FS`)?: something like `awk -F '[\t |]+' '{print $3, $4}' `

Comment: A funny tested OK one: `awk -v FS="|" -v OFS="\t" '{$1=$1}1' input`

Comment: With the benefit of hindsight:
Your question is an example of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/248777),
Y is "how do I use `sed` to preprocess input for `awk`?"
X is the actual problem, best addressed with  "use `awk` to handle your input _directly_". 
An answer to Y was given, while exhorting you to consider X, the basics of which @LarsFischer's comment demonstrates.
Not only did you not acknowledge either, you chose to accept a _variant_ of Y, which uses a different tool than requested ("do Y _with `awk`_"), yet in a decidedly suboptimal manner.

Comment: @mklement0, I accepted the `awk` based on what others suggested. As I am learning `awk` I began to look more into a solution that you and others already knew. I used the great example as a reference point and tried another way. My science is better than my programming and a appreciate everyone's help. Thank you very much :).

Comment: @Chris: Accepting the `awk` answer you accepted is _not_ what others (including me) were recommending. The actual recommendation was _not to try to pre-process your input file_ for _later_ use with `awk`, because `awk` _can do it all in one step_. The `awk` answer you accepted does _not_  demonstrate that - it's just another pre-processing answer that happens to use `awk` - and as such doesn't even answer your question _as asked_.

Comment: By contrast, Lars Fischer's comment - `awk -F '[\t |]+' '...'` - _does_ point you in the right direction: how to set `-F` (which sets `FS`, the input field separator) to a regular expression that allows you to recognize not just the whitespace-separated tokens as fields, but also the two fields contained in tokens such as `955763|AGRN` - which means there is no need for pre-preprocessing the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{sub(/\|/,"\t")}1' file

chr1    955542  955763  AGRN
chr1    957570  957852  AGRN
chr1    976034  976270  AGRN
```

Comment: To put the acceptance of this answer into perspective: (a) the question was specifically about `sed`, (b) an answer was given based on that premise, (c) several people pointed out that using `sed` to _prepare_ input for later use by `awk` is not necessary, because `awk` can do it all, (d) Lars Fischer showed how to do just that with `awk` in a comment on the question.
There's nothing wrong with this answer per se, but it does nothing more than what was asked of the `sed` command, so it neither answers the question as asked, nor does it show a _better_ way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want a two-step approach, where you remove `|` chars. first and then feed the result to `awk` (instead of doing it all in `awk` - see [Lars Fischer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4086774/lars-fischer)'s comment on the question<sup>[1]</sup>
), the simplest approach is:

```
  tr '|' '\t' < input > out
```

Incidentally, your `sed` command doesn't produce the output you quote.
To do it in `sed` (which is overkill here, unless you want the convenience of in-place updating with `-i`), you'd need:

```
 # GNU Sed
 sed 's/|/\t/g'  input

 # BSD/OSX Sed, from bash/ksh/zsh:
 sed 's/|/'$'\t''/g'  input

 # Fully POSIX-compliant (from a shell that doesn't support $'...' strings)
 sed 's/|/'"$(printf '\t')"'/g' input
```

---

<sup>[1] To add an explanation: `awk -F '[\t |]+' '...'` sets `-F` (which sets special `awk` variable `FS`, the input field separator) to a regular expression that allows you to recognize not just the whitespace-separated tokens as fields, but also the two fields contained in tokens such as `955763|AGRN` - which means there is no need for pre-preprocessing the input.

Regex `[\t |]+` means: consider any nonempty run of any mix of tabs, spaces, and pipe symbols a field separator.</sup>

Comment: Note that `$'\t'` is a bashism, and might not even work on BSD/OSX depending on the shell being used. It looks like it will be POSIX one day, but as of 2016 isn't.

Comment: @Thanks, Jens, that's why I added `from bash/ksh/zsh` (the syntax actually originated in ksh93, and was later adopted by both Bash and Zsh).

Comment: Both commands result in the same `current output` where the ~\~is removed but there is no tab.  I will look into `awk` as well.  Thank you :).

Comment: @mklement0, sorry the ~\~ was a typo... yes you are correct remove the `|` and replace it with a tab.  I apologize and thank you :).

Comment: @Chris you seem to be missing the key point that if you're doing this to format your input to pass along to an awk command - that's completely unnecessary, awk can handle the input as-is.